# Как организовать вывод товаров

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, посоветуйте правильный подход. Реализую что то вроде магазина запчастей, Задача: вывести определенные запчасти по модели машины и по типу запчасти.

Есть таблица **category** с полями *id, title*, таблица products c полями *id, category_id, title, price* и таблица **car_models**.

Вывожу тип запчасти только по модели, не знаю как связать все это, чтобы при выборе модели машины отображались категории запчасти (тип запчасти) и при выборе типа запчасти отображались конкретные запчасти. Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте в запросе указывать WHERE = "{условие}"

Comment: Либо INNER JOIN, который соединит Вам все 3 таблицы (1 запрос), либо получаем данные по отдельности (3 запроса) и выводим как нужно. Выбор одного из вариантов зависит от кол-ва данных